# django mysql-client or mysql-db error

Tags: django, python-3.x, mysql-python

I am facing these errors when I am running the python manage.py runserver
Also i have tried:

1.pip install MySQL-python
 2.pip install mysql-python

but nothing worked.I need help

[Errors i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgbQU.png)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem time ago.. I solved it doing this:

1) for Windows:

```
$ pip3 install mysqlclient
```

2) for Linux:

```
$ pip3 install mysqlclient
```

if fails with "mysql_config not found" you have to do (only linux):

```
$ apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

Of course, use pip instead of pip3 if you're working with python2.7